# Markup generic type does not get resolved

Tags: typescript

Our angular guy wants me to replace our autogenerated DTOs with interfaces instead of classes. Today it looks like this

```
export class Query<TResult> {
    private _dummyTResult:TResult;
}
```

_dummyTResult:TResult is a workaround to get the generic parameter to be usable later on. With interfaces this is not possible. Given this dummy code

```
interface MyDto {
    id:number
}

interface Query<TResult> { }



interface MyQuery extends Query<MyDto> {
    foo:string
}

function executeQuery<TResult>(query : Query<TResult>) : TResult {      
    return {} as TResult; //Mocked backend call
}

const dto:MyQuery = { foo: "bar"};

const result = executeQuery(dto); //Result is unknown here
```

The type of result is not resolved and is unknown. Can this be solved or do we need to stay  with classes?

Update:
The private member is not visible for the developers.

[image]

Sure its accessible if you really want to but we only care about typescript design time from VS Code.

Comment: Technically, you could add optional filed to your interface too, `__private?: TResult`, it will work more or less same as your current solution with classes. But it will also change public 'API' of interface, which isn't desirable I assume

Comment: @OlegWock The public API of the class will also contain information about the private member (its existence is visible from outside, you just can't access it), so I don't think that makes much of a difference. I'd do something like `__dummyTResult?: TResult` in this case also. @Anders, does that fully address the question? If so then someone (hopefully @OlegWock) will write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Comment: It can not be public because I do not want the user of the query API to be forced to set that property. Its only used as a markup type so the executeQuery function can have a nice interface

Comment: It's optional so nobody has to set it. See the `?` in the two comments preceding?

Comment: ah true. But its visible to the devs from VS Code

Comment: The private property is also "visible", it's just not something they can read/write. Visibility and access control are different.  Surely now we're digressing, though, right? I don't see anything in your question that would preclude such an answer based on "visibility to developer".  Is such a thing a requirement?

Comment: See my edit of the orignal question please

Comment: • [Is an image of your IDE necessary here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) Can you express that as plaintext so that there's no requirement that only sighted people view this question or that they have to view it with a particular screen or font size? • By "visible" you apparently mean "autosuggested". Is it a *requirement* that the dummy property not be autosuggested? If so, please [edit] to state that explicitly (just saying that the current thing *isn't* autosuggested isn't the same) and then we can write "no, it's an overconstrained problem with no solution."

Comment: Its not only auto suggested. You get a compile time error both in VS code and angular if you try to use it.

Comment: Unless you do [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WKXLGw). I guess at this point we're just nailing down semantics of what "visible" means? In any case could you [edit] the question as I asked before? That is, either replace or supplement any images of IDE stuff with a plaintext version, and to explicitly say that you require that the dummy property be "invisible" in the way you mean it?